# defining a view based upon a int

Tags: android, view

is there anyway to change which view you are editing based upon the value of a int?

Without using a if statement?

for example:

```
int counter = 1;

public void attach(){
final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1)
TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2)
TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3)
TextView text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4)

if (counter < 5){
if (sp.getInt("test" + counter , 0) == counter){

text + counter .setText("test" + counter);

}else{counter = counter + 1; attach();}}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to define an array of possible view IDs.

```
int[] viewIds = new int[] {
    R.id.text1,
    R.id.text2,
    R.id.text3,
    R.id.text4
}

//some code
int i = /*whatever*/;
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(viewIds[i]);
tv.setText("test"+i);
```